# Symfony 2/3 REST API Validation without form

Tags: php, symfony, validation

Let's say I have a `Cat` entity with  a property `$name` (string).

I send to url POST /cats with parameter `[name = 123]` (an integer).

How I can validate data from request without form? Or REST API with form validation it's normal? I can't find information about validation without form.

I can use the Validation component without form, but maybe there is a better approach than `$this->get('validator')->validate('data from request')`.

Comment: A similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324782/validating-entities-without-form-in-symfony-2

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend still using a Form to handle validation, and you can simulate the submit manually: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html#calling-form-submit-manually

A very simplified example could then be something like below.

```
$formFactory = new Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory();

//build your "post" data from your submitted content via api
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), TRUE);

//build your Form and Entity objects.
$formType = new Path\To\CatForm(); //for example
$entity = new Path\To\CatEntity();

$parameters = array();
$method = 'POST';

$form = $formFactory->create($formType, $entity, ['method' => $method]);
$form->submit($parameters, ($method == 'PATCH' ? false : true));

if ($form->isValid()) {
    //do stuff
}
```